# Upload large file - 502 bad gateway error on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem when I upload the large file on Azure. I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5.0 API project.
I have implemented functionality regarding [Microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming). Moreover, I added a pooling mechanism so the frontend application has another endpoint to check upload status.
Everything works fine when I run locally but I have a problem with a large file on Azure. My API is using Azure App Service Premium P1v3. It returns a 502 bad gateway for large files (above 1GB).

I made a tests and 98 % time consuming is reading stream. From Microsft docs it is:

```
if (MultipartRequestHelper
                .HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {
                untrustedFileNameForStorage = contentDisposition.FileName.Value;
                // Don't trust the file name sent by the client. To display
                // the file name, HTML-encode the value.
                trustedFileNameForDisplay = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(
                        contentDisposition.FileName.Value);

                streamedFileContent = 
                    await FileHelpers.ProcessStreamedFile(section, contentDisposition, 
                        ModelState, _permittedExtensions, _fileSizeLimit);

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
            }
```

I know there is a load balancer timeout of 230 seconds on Azure App Service but when I test it using postman in most cases 502 is being returned after 30 seconds.

Maybe I need to set some configuration feature on Azure App Service? Always on is enabled.

I would like to stay with Azure App Service, but I was thinking about migrating to Azure App service or allow the Frontend application to upload files directly to Azure Blob Storage.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Hello, I am facing a very similar issue but using NodeJs, were you able to solve this? I have been struggling with this for days

Answer (score 0):

Facing similar issue on uploading document of larger size(up to 100MB) through as.net core api hosted as azure app gateway and have set timeout to 10min and applied these attributes on action
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
Even kestrel has configured to accept 200MB
UseKestrel(options =>

```
               {
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715200;
                    options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                });
```

The file content is in base64 format in request object.
Appreciate if any help on this problem.